# Modify the resource path for a sub-sample in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded a user journey in JMeter (using AngularJS). When I click a link that spawns a GET request to a page, in-turn it spawns additional sub-requests to some page resources (images).

In Short:

```
Test Plan
-- Thread Group
---- Transaction Controller
------ HTTP Request (Main sample)
```

Here the main sample triggers additional sub-samples for resources and they fail due to path issues however this works manually using a browser.

I am in need to change the path of the sub-samples or not fail on a 404 for these sub-samples.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are getting different results in browser and JMeter indicates that your JMeter test is not well-behaved as it doesn't replicate browser requests with 100% accuracy therefore your load test doesn't make a lot of sense as "good" load tests must represent real user sitting behind real browser as close as possible. I would recommend comparing requests which are being sent from browser and JMeter with a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), identify the differences and amend JMeter configuration so JMeter-driven requests would be exact replica of browser-driven ones (apart from dynamic parameters)

For the time being I can tell you only how to convert failed sub-samples into successful ones.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your main request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.getSubResults().each {
       it.setSuccessful(true)
   }
   ```

That's it, the above [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code will mark all sub-samples as successful no matter of original status (the response status code, message, body, etc. will remain original, JMeter just won't consider them as failed anymore). See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Its a simple static page call that has an image resource that is embedded.
<img src="content/images/img.png">

As the app url and context root is:
https://application.url/appContextRoot/pages/views/dashboard.html

Now in theory when the above resource is rendered, it is supposed to find the image at: https://application.url/appContextRoot/pages/views/content/images/img.png 

However the image is at the following location and being rendered correctly by the browser but not using JMeter: https://application.url/appContextRoot/content/images/img.png (this I got from Fiddler)

Comment: As for the solution, is there a way to modify the sub-sample url?

Comment: You can untick `Follow redirects` and `Redirect Automatically` boxes in the parent [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and add another sampler to directly download the image using the correct URL. The aggregate time of the page load you can get using i.e. [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller).